# What is relation between IIS application pool and Database(Ex: SQL Server)?

Tags: iis, pool

---

Hi,

What is the relation between **IIS application pool** and **Database**(Ex: SQL Server) for a ASP.NET application?
Does any changes in IIS application pool configuration effect database connections? or vice versa?

How does SQL Server maintain the **connection pool**, in conjunction with **application pool**? 
Does it maintains **single connection pool** for all different asp.net applications, if they use same connection string and from same application pool? What if they are from different application pool and same connection string?

Comment: Do you use ASP.NET or another technique? Please be more specific, as IIS itself does not connect to database. If you happen to use ASP.NET, you should start from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht43wsex(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Sorry for incomplete question. Yes, its for ASP.NET application.